# How can turn on feature of move or copy option in Sharepoint 2019?

Tags: sharepoint

I have Sharepoint subsite, and looking to enable copy and move options for users to move files from one location to another within that subsite.

Answer (score 0):

You may try Site Content and Structure currently.

/_layouts/15/sitemanager.aspx

Test demo in my local.

[image]

[one thread for your reference](https://www.koskila.net/help-my-content-and-structure-page-in-sharepoint-online-is-gone/)

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for sharing this valuable information, But I am using SharePoint 2019 and I would like to see how does that work?

Comment: This is I tested in my 2019, you could copy/move the files by 'Actions' menu.